# Queries about ReactiveX programming with swift

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift, reactivex, rx-cocoa

A completed project in swift 3.0, I want to update it with ReactiveX frameworks for swift i.e rxSwift, rxCocoa.

My point is as i'm learning reactive it is so different and new for me. 
But before doing this I have some question in my mind

1. Is it worth working, spending time on ReactiveX?
2. Does it increase the performance of the application?
3. What do you personally think about the future of ReactiveX?

Answer (score 1):

There are certain topics of contention in the rx-world. I will give u that.
But if ur previous project version did not have rx (in any language), then changes are its bulky.

Imagine this:-
Without Rx:- (we need to pull data)
- u query a data structure/function/service
- a value is returned

With Rx:- (data is already pushed down to us, we do not need to req. separately, but just subscribe)
- values are always available on subscription

Rx changes the way u look at file systems/events, etc. 
They are all viewed as data-streams which can be emitted using an Observable.
An observer can then request it on subscription.

So, it is the future and yes the code is reduced severely and much much readable.

Comment: So in your opinion i should not move to Rx in this project as i have to change a lot. well ok. But you didn't mention anything about the performance.

Comment: depends on what u want to achieve. if u wanna be generation next ready, u should move to rx style of coding, whichever programming lang u r using.

Answer (score 1):

learning curve is steep, but eventually you end up writing much less code (like you can forget delegates altogether)

for existing projects, it will be a lot of hassle especially if not the whole team is on the same level rx-wise

performance-wise no noticeable difference

(IMHO)